# SSL login and registration over JSONP

Tags: security, authentication, https, jsonp

I would like to keep my site's login & registration secured over SSL.  Instead of redirecting users to a dedicated SSL page, I'd like to have the site's login & registration forms appear in an overlay, so that no page refresh is needed after login.

I haven't seen any larger sites use this method.  Sites like Youtube, Delicious and FriendFeed redirect users to a dedicated SSL page.  Facebook does a form post from http to https.  And other sites like Digg and reddit just skip using SSL altogether.

Is there a reason why no one is using SSL over JSONP for user authentication?   I'm not storing sensitive data like personal info or any e-commerce related info. But I would like to secure email addresses and passwords.

Comment: How would JSONP work in this scenario exactly? It is not just a string format structure with padding to prevent XSS attacks?

Comment: I'd use JSONP to make an "Ajax" request to an SSL page from an HTTP page.  So a <script> tag would be attached to the DOM, with src pointing to a page hosted on SSL.  Username and password would be passed as GET params.

Comment: But your users really like to see login form loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: Do they?  Facebook gets away with posting to HTTPs from HTTP on their homepage.  Digg and Reddit skip it entirely.  To clarify, I'm not storing sensitive data like personal info or info used for purchases.  But I would like to secure email addresses and passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't much point in using HTTPS for only the login because you are still violating [OWASP A9](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  An attacker can still use an application like [FireSheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) to hijack the session id.  Service that care about security such as gmail and gihub,  soon to be facebook and twitter  use HTTPS for the life of the session.

In terms of JSONP,  make sure the client's request is HTTPS and further more make sure the proxied request is also HTTPS,  although this is not as vital as the first hop.  As always don't forget about [CSRF and JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: Using SSL on login helps in that it prevents the username and password from being sent over plain text.  If the username and password were intercepted, a user's account would be permanently compromised.  If a user's session id is hijacked, it's only useful for the duration of the session.  The link you posted is helpful, I'm thinking no one uses SSL JSONP login because of "Mixed SSL on a page should be avoided since it causes user warnings in the browser, and may expose the user’s session ID. "

Comment: OWASP is right.  But using SSL on login prevents the username/password from being sent in plain text.  That's why sites like FriendFeed, Delicious and Facebook mix SSL logins with http content.  Of course if you are dealing with truly sensitive data, you should move everything to SSL.

Comment: @user473044 yes and toughs sites are hacked with FireSheep.  The session ID is as good as a username/password.  I don't see any point what so ever in just encrypting the login,  thats very short sighted.

Comment: True.  But Firesheep only works if the victim is connected to a public wifi network.  Maybe that's why Facebook, Youtube etc think they can get away with it.  Or on the other hand, why Digg and Reddit don't even bother with SSL at all, since they don't feel SSL login would accomplish anything.  :)

Comment: Rook: A lot of users use the same passwords for multiple services. If the user/pass is sent in plain text an attacker can get access to multiple services instead of just one service. Using SSL on all requests is of course preferred, but encrypting just the login is still better than no encryption at all.

Comment: @heyman If you aren't going to properly protect your service to the point where someone sitting next to you can login as you,  then why even have a password in the first place?

Comment: @Rook You're missing the point. The fact that a lot of users use the same passwords for multiple services is an argument for at least using SSL for the login, rather than having all traffic unsecured. Here's an example: A site which purpose it is to allow users to collect pictures of funny cats. For most users of this site, it wouldn't be a catastrophe if their account was hacked. But it could *definitely* be a catastrophe if the attacker also got access to their e-mail or bank account.

Comment: @heyman  why even have passwords if you let people just walk into your website?

Comment: I'm sorry but this just feels like a Straw Man Argument (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).

Comment: @heyman its trivial to prevent this attack, its trivial to carry out this attack.  Its an OWASP violation and it will be a finding on any penetration test you pay for.  HTTPS must be the default for all web applications that use authentication, not just for google and facebook.